# How can get the correct Handler of an object?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, handler

I am making an application that requires generating panels dynamically, and in turn that each panel generated two events, one with left click and another with right mouse click.
The right click is the one that gives me trouble since I have not been able to call a Handler that I have put temporarily in the event of the left click, but now that I see that it works, I want to pass it to the ToolStripMenuItem event, but when it enters event, the sender takes ownership of the ToolStripMenuItem and in this case you would need the property "System.Windows.Forms.Panel" in order to work on the Panel object.

I am not sure if I am doing it correctly, can you support me with any idea how to do it?

Annex the code of what I have developed so far

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim pb, pbdoors As New Panel

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim pos As Int32 = 20
        Dim contador As Int16 = 1

        For i As Int16 = 1 To 3

            Dim pb As New Panel With
            {
                .Width = 120,
                .Height = 460,
                .Top = 10,
                .Left = 10,
                .Name = "Panel" & contador,
                .Location = New Point(pos, 20)
            }

            AddHandler pb.Click, AddressOf myClickHandler_b

            Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(pb)

            pb.BringToFront()

            pos = pos + 120
            contador = contador + 1
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

Public Sub myClickHandler_b(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim pos As Integer = Val(TextBox38.Text)
    Dim clickedLabel As Panel = DirectCast(sender, Panel)
    clickedLabel.Location = New Point((clickedLabel.Location.X + 120), clickedLabel.Location.Y)

    TextBox38.Text = pos
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem1.Click
    myClickHandler_b(sender, e)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to recognize which mouse button is clicked you should use MouseClick as event handler.
The piece of code starting with and working on that is: `“AddHandler pb.MouseClick……….”` 
I hope this might help you:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim pos As Int32 = 20
    Dim contador As Int16 = 1

    For i As Int16 = 1 To 3

        Dim pb As New Panel With
    {
        .Width = 120,
        .Height = 460,
        .Top = 10,
        .Left = 10,
        .Name = "Panel" & contador,
        .Location = New Point(pos, 20)
    }

        AddHandler pb.MouseClick, Sub(senderO As Object, eObj As MouseEventArgs)
                                      If eObj.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
                                          'Do your tasks here
                                          MsgBox("Left button clicked")
                                      ElseIf eObj.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then

                                          'Do your tasks here
                                          MsgBox("Right button clicked")
                                      End If
                                  End Sub



        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(pb)

        pb.BringToFront()

        pos = pos + 120
        contador = contador + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, just a question, the `Sub` how execute the conditional? send the operations in the handler? or how?

Comment: I don't think this will work for him, since he wants to be able to call the handler from another place. Maybe `RaiseEvent`, but still.

Comment: That Sub is called “Anonymous” and is like an external Sub (more helpful in various scenarios).
If you need to call this from different places you should create an external Sub and manage handlers with AdHandler.MouseClick , AddressOf YourExternalSub.
After that you sholud test your sender parameter If TypeOf (senderO) Is Panel Then DoSomething otherwise DoSomethingElse

Answer (score 0):

Winforms only provides a single event (`Click`) for both mouse buttons. You need to check (and cast, given that signature) the event arguments to know when you have a right click:

```
Public Sub myClickHandler_b(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim mouseevent As MouseEventArgs = TryCast(e, MouseEventArgs)
    If mouseevent IsNot Nothing AndAlso mouseevent.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        RightClick(TryCast(sender, Panel))
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Left Click

                         'Ugh. Val() is not your friend.
    Dim pos As Integer = Val(TextBox38.Text)
    Dim clickedLabel As Control = DirectCast(sender, Control)
    clickedLabel.Location = New Point((clickedLabel.Location.X + 120), clickedLabel.Location.Y)

    TextBox38.Text = pos
End Sub

Public Sub RightClick(source As Panel)

End Sub
```

Now for the second part. In the `ToolStripMenuItem1_Click()` method, if you have several dynamic panels on your form, how is the method supposed to know which panel it's working with? You need something in this code knows that information, and uses it for the `sender` argument. Additionally, given the new handling for left vs right clicks, you also need to think carefully about how that will spill over into the click handler.

So `ToolStripMenuItem1_Click()` should look something (but probably not exactly!) like this:

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem1.Click
    myClickHandler_b(pb, Nothing)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Joel Coehoorn, thank you for your answer. I have just a question, in this case, qhen I press the click left in ToolStripMenuItem, in "sender" have the text from the ToolStripMenuItem, and the MouseEventArgs is empty, this is an issue? or what is my issue? Attach the code in other comment. Thank you.

Comment: It's okay for the eventargs to be empty, but not for the sender. `myClickHandler()` could be used for several different panels. Therefore, **before** you can call that method, you have to know _which Panel_ you want to use. When you have a reference for that panel, you can pass it as the sender.